# Filtering By Params (descending) - in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying Filterable, https://gist.github.com/justinweiss/9065666, for filtering in Rails.
Having issues while trying to get things filtered in descending order, and need some advice whats best way to continue.

Here is the code in model:

```
scope :filter_by_first_name, ->(first_name) { where(first_name: first_name) }
```

In controller:

```
Model.filter_by(filtered_params).order(params[:order])
```

Now I am trying to filter by first_name in descending order, here is how I do it with the created_at
url and params:

> website-url.com/model?order=-created_at

By just adding '-' in front of created_at it gives them filtered in descending order.
Now when filtering first_name,

> website-url.com/model?order=first_name

This is working well, but when I add '-' in the beginning of first_name, then it does not affect the filtering at all, same like I would write empty order `order=''`

Thank you

Comment: timestamps are technically numerical values so putting  sign in front of them makes sense. but a `-` sign as a char is not going to act same way.

Comment: happy you understood my problem, I thought I didn't explain it well. I was wondering what is the best direction on creating DESC for first_name to keep consistency in the model and avoid writing a lot of code in the controller